# Why does TikZ crop one of my pdfs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am including some (already cropped) pdfs into a tikzfile. 
One of them gets further cropping when I include it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics{breve-crop.pdf}};%%%%%%%%%right side of breve-crop.pdf cut out
\node at (0,1) {\includegraphics{longa-crop.pdf}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: Original PDF]

[image: After inclusion]

Comment: Can you reproduce using one of the sample images e.g. `example-image-a` or whatever? If not, we can't reproduce without the images you are using. I cannot even tell where one image ends and the next begins. (I guess 2 bits are part of one image?) Try adding `draw` to the nodes to see the bouding boxes. I assume that the second is painting over the first i.e. you've not left enough space.  But it is impossible to tell, really, without more information.

Comment: I'd like to upload the pdfs, but I couldn't see an option.

Comment: No, you can't upload PDFs here, only JPGs and PNGs, so you'd need to use something like Dropbox.

Comment: You can't. If you cannot reproduce the problem any other way, you'd have to make them available elsewhere and post links. But add `draw` first as that is likely to make the problem obvious to you.

Comment: Sorry, how do I add draw? \node at (0,1) {\includegraphics{longa-crop.pdf}}; \draw ...?

Comment: Sorry, I got the problem. It's  ps2eps that crops the image too much.

Comment: No, `\node [draw] {...};`, that will draw the outline of the node.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by `ps2eps`, which is not mentioned in the question, and has been diagnosed and resolved by the OP independently. (See comments.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the end I found that the problem was ps2eps, which trimmed too much while creating the pdf. Basically it could have been a problem with paper measures and lilypond: resetting the page to default and retrimming with ps2eps produced a perfect image